# I want to stored data of client side slider in temporary using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

1. I have using one slider from client side that slider containing 4
   question n question having 4 option of the answer.
2. user have select any one from them n go to next question.
3. I want to that user selected answer in temporarily stored in some where         using javascript.
4. How to create the javascript for that.end

---

[image]

**code:**

```html
   <div class='home' style="background-color: #e4ceb4 !important">
        <section class='start-invest'>
            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='unslider' data-unslider='true' id='unslider' style='display:none;'>
                    <ul class='nolist'>
                        <li>
                            <div class='slide-counter'>
                                <div class='inner-d'>
                                    <span>1/4</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 1 -->
                            <div class='hide' data-slide-no='1'></div>
                            <div class='start-heading'>Start your Investment Plan</div>
                            <!-- For Mobile -->
                            <div class='slider-nav'>
                                <span>1</span>/4
                            </div>
                            <div class='age-income'>
                                I am
                                <input autocomplete='off' autofocus class='age' id='age' maxlength='2' placeholder='' tabindex='1' type='text'>
                                years old &amp;
                                <br class='br'>
                                earn
                                <br class='break'>a
                                Gross annual income
                                <br class='br'>of
                                <i class='fa fa-inr'></i>
                                <input class='income' id='income' maxlength='13' placeholder='' tabindex='2' type='text'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='cta-next'>
                                <button class='btn' id='next-btn' tabindex='3'>
                                    Next
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class='slide-counter'>
                                <div class='inner-d'>
                                    <span>2/4</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 2 -->
                            <div class='hide' data-slide-no='2'></div>
                            <div class='start-heading'>Start your Investment Plan</div>
                            <!-- For Mobile -->
                            <div class='slider-nav'>
                                <span>2</span>/4
                            </div>
                            <div class='age-income'>
                                How long do you intend
                                <br class='br'>to
                                remain invested?
                            </div>
                            <div class='btn-set' id="Opt1">
                                <button id="Opt5" name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn risk-by-time-btns" data-risk-factor="10.5" value="1 to 3 yrs">1 to 3 yrs</button>
                                <button id="Opt2" name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn risk-by-time-btns" data-risk-factor="24.5" value="3 to 5 yrs">3 to 5 yrs</button>
                                <button id="Opt3" name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn risk-by-time-btns" data-risk-factor="28" value="5 to 7 yrs">5 to 7 yrs</button>
                                <button id="Opt4" name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn risk-by-time-btns" data-risk-factor="31.5" value="Greater than 7 yrs">Greater than 7 yrs</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class='slide-counter'>
                                <div class='inner-d'>
                                    <span>3/4</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 3 -->
                            <div class='hide' data-slide-no='3'></div>
                            <div class='start-heading'>Start your Investment Plan</div>
                            <!-- For Mobile -->
                            <div class='slider-nav'>
                                <span>3</span>/4
                            </div>
                            <div class='age-income'>
                                What are you looking at from your
                                <br class='br'>investment?
                            </div>
                            <div class='btn-set'>
                                <button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn goal-btns" data-risk-factor="10.5">
                                    Safety
                                    <br class='br'>
                                    <span class='tip'>I prioritise safety of my principal at the top and expect to achieve returns that equal inflation</span>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn lg goal-btns" data-risk-factor="17.5">
                                    Safety +
                                    <br class='br-lg'>
                                    Moderate Growth
                                    <br class='br'>
                                    <span class='tip'>While I would like to protect my principal, I will be happy with returns that beat inflation</span>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn goal-btns" data-risk-factor="26.25">
                                    Growth
                                    <br class='br'>
                                    <span class='tip'>I seek to grow my capital in line with the stock market performance over a longer period of time while being able to accept short term volatilities</span>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn goal-btns lg" data-risk-factor="31.5">
                                    Aggressive
                                    <br class='br-lg'>
                                    Growth
                                    <br class='br'>
                                    <span class='tip'>I would like to take the stock market returns and beat them hands down with my portfolio performance! I will digest the volatility that accompanies my style</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li id='risk-buttons'>
                            <div class='slide-counter'>
                                <div class='inner-d'>
                                    <span>4/4</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 4 -->
                            <div class='hide' data-slide-no='4'></div>
                            <div class='start-heading'>Start your Investment Plan</div>
                            <!-- For Mobile -->
                            <div class='slider-nav'>
                                <span>4</span>/4
                            </div>
                            <div class='age-income'>
                                How do you rate yourself
                                <br class='br'>
                                on Risk Tolerance?
                                <sup>*</sup>
                            </div>
                            <!-- For Mobile -->
                            <div class='risk-sm'>
                                * Risk tolerance is an important component in investing. An individual should have a realistic understanding of
                                <br class='br-lg'>
                                his or her ability and willingness to stomach large swings in the value of his or her investments.
                            </div>
                            <div class='btn-set'>
                                <button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn sure risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="3">
                                    Very Low
                                    <span class='tip'>I cannot tolerate any loss</span>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn sure risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="6">
                                    Low
                                    <span class='tip'>I can tolerate up to 5% loss in a short term dip</span>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn sure risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="9">
                                    Medium
                                    <span class='tip'>I can tolerate up to a 10% loss in a short term dip</span>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn sure risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="11.25">
                                    High
                                    <span class='tip'>I can tolerate up to a 25% loss in a short term dip</span>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn sure risk-willingness-btns" id="very_high_tolerance" data-risk-factor="13.5">
                                    Very High
                                    <span class='tip'>I can tolerate greater than 25% loss in a short term dip</span>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn unsure risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="0">
                                    Unsure
                                    <span class='tip'></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class='cta hide' id='okay-cta'>
                                <small>Still unsure? Answer a few more questions for us!</small>
                                <br>
                                <button class='btn' id='okay-btn'>OKAY</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class='cta hide' id='compute-cta'>
                                <button class='btncompute btn compute' id="compute" onclick=" Progressbar()">COMPUTE</button><div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- For Desktop -->
                            <div class='risk-lg'>
                                * Risk tolerance is an important component in investing. An individual should have a realistic understanding of
                                <br class='br-lg'>
                                his or her ability and willingness to stomach large swings in the value of his or her investments.
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- 4.1 -->
                        <li>
                            <div class='slide-counter'>
                                <div class='inner-d'>
                                    <span>
                                        4.1 /
                                        <br>4.4</br>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='hide' data-slide-no='5'></div>
                            <div class='start-heading'>Start your Investment Plan</div>
                            <!-- For Mobile -->
                            <div class='slider-nav'>
                                <span>4</span>/4
                            </div>
                            <div class='age-income'>
                                By how much would your investments need
                                <br class='break'>
                                to go down to cause you discomfort?
                            </div>
                            <div class='btn-set'>
                                <button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn investment-fall-threshold-btns" data-risk-factor="0.75">
                                    Any fall
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn investment-fall-threshold-btns" data-risk-factor="1.5">
                                    By 10%
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn investment-fall-threshold-btns" data-risk-factor="2.25">
                                    By 25%
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn investment-fall-threshold-btns" data-risk-factor="3.375">
                                    By more than 25%
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- 4.2 -->
                        <li>
                            <div class='slide-counter'>
                                <div class='inner-d'>
                                    <span>
                                        4.2 /
                                        <br>4.4</br>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='hide' data-slide-no='6'></div>
                            <div class='start-heading'>Start your Investment Plan</div>
                            <!-- For Mobile -->
                            <div class='slider-nav'>
                                <span>4</span>/4
                            </div>
                            <div class='age-income'>
                                While making investments, what do you care for most?
                            </div>
                            <div class='btn-set'>
                                <button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn lg investment-care-btns" data-risk-factor="0.75">
                                    Minimizing Losses
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn lg investment-care-btns" data-risk-factor="1.875">
                                    Both Equally
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn lg investment-care-btns" data-risk-factor="3.375">
                                    Maximising Gains
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- 4.3 -->
                        <li>
                            <div class='slide-counter'>
                                <div class='inner-d'>
                                    <span>
                                        4.3 /
                                        <br>4.4</br>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='hide' data-slide-no='7'></div>
                            <div class='start-heading'>Start your Investment Plan</div>
                            <!-- For Mobile -->
                            <div class='slider-nav'>
                                <span>4</span>/4
                            </div>
                            <div class='age-income'>
                                While deciding between two jobs,
                                <br class='break'>
                                which will you go for?
                            </div>
                            <div class='btn-set'>
                                <button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn lg job-choice-btns" data-risk-factor="0.75">
                                    The one with high job security
                                    <br class='break'>
                                    and low pay increase
                                    </br>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn lg job-choice-btns" data-risk-factor="1.875">
                                    Can't say as it depends on
                                    <br class='break'>
                                    other factors as well
                                    </br>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn optn-btn lg job-choice-btns" data-risk-factor="3.375">
                                    The one with less job security
                                    <br class='break'>
                                    but high pay increase
                                    </br>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- 4.4t -->
                        <li>
                            <div class='slide-counter'>
                                <div class='inner-d'>
                                    <span>
                                        4.4 /
                                        <br>4.4</br>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='hide' data-slide-no='8'></div>
                            <div class='start-heading'>Start your Investment Plan</div>
                            <!-- For Mobile -->
                            <div class='slider-nav'>
                                <span>4</span>/4
                            </div>
                            <div class='age-income'>
                                How do you rate your willingness to take investment
                                <br class='break'>
                                risks relative to the general population?
                            </div>
                            <div class='btn-set'>
                                <button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn relative-risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="0.75">
                                    Very Low
                                    <br class='break risk-rel-pop'>
                                    Risk-taker
                                    </br>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn relative-risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="1.5">
                                    Low
                                    <br class='break risk-rel-pop'>
                                    Risk-taker
                                    </br>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn relative-risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="2.25">
                                    Medium
                                    <br class='break risk-rel-pop'>
                                    Risk-taker
                                    </br>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn relative-risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="2.8125">
                                    High
                                    <br class='break risk-rel-pop'>
                                    Risk-taker
                                    </br>
                                </button><button name="button" type="submit" class="wh-btn relative-risk-willingness-btns" data-risk-factor="3.375">
                                    Very High
                                    <br class='break risk-rel-pop'>
                                    Risk-taker
                                    </br>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class='cta'>
                                <button class='btn compute hide btncompute' onclick=" Progressbar()" id="compute">COMPUTE</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="unslider-arrow next tooltip" href="#">
                        <span class='error-message'>
                            ZAPP!
                            <br>
                            Please pick an
                            <br>
                            option before we
                            <br>
                            move ahead.
                        </span>
                        <span class='error-message-input'></span>
                    </a><a class="unslider-arrow prev" href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class='hide' id='progress'>
            <div class='wrapper of-hidden'>
                <div class='orange-text'></div>
                <div class='white-text'></div>
                <div class="safari chart" data-percent="100" style="align-content: center ;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 6em">
                    <img class="tag" src="~/Image/spinner.gif" style="align-content: center ;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 6em" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage to store data on client-side

Comment: HOW TO I DNT KNW HOW TO USE IT @Auine